# How can I undefine the System Definitions of Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, macros, compiler-flags

I use Visual Studio 2012 to edit source code that is targeting Linux. The problem is that syntax highlighting gets it all wrong, because it thinks _WIN32, _MSC_VER, and similar macros are defined. What can I do to get rid of them?

I tried two methods:

1. added /u command in the property page for C++;
2. added /U"_WIN32" /U"_MSC_VER" and so on.

but without any effect. The problem is the same in Visual Studio 2013.

What should I do?

Comment: Does it *matter* if you leave them defined? They're not hurting anything, just leave them be. Besides, you never know if a 3rd-party library might need them.

Comment: I just use it to scan the code of linux project. The definitions will affect the code.

Comment: The code will be the same. Those definitions only affect how the code is compiled. And if you have platform (i.e. linux-) specific parts in it, you probably *need* them so MSVC does not fall over code it does not know during compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are compiler-predefined macros. You can only `#undef` them in the code. Use a custom header file, probably.

Anyway, the requirement seems strange to me. Why do you use MSVC if you want to scan the *Linux* code? If the Linux code uses any GCC extensions (it often does), it can't compile under MSVC at all.

Comment: I just use it to scan code not compile. Because I am familiar with the hot keys in the Visual Studio.

Comment: The method you offer is helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit them in you're project's configuration.

Right click project->properties->C/C++->preprocessor->preprocessor definitions

Comment: I undefine all the definitions include inherit from the parent.

Comment: You're right, Visual Studio defined them anyway, even with /u. If this is really necessary, you can #undef them, this works in release mode but not in debug.

Answer (score 0):

I create a test project. The definitions only affected when the code be compiled.